# SQL Reports - sorting an column based on the date mentioned in another column adjacent to it

Tags: sql

It would be great if someone can help me out. I am new to SQL. 
This is what my table data is

table name: emp

```
e_no    e_name        e_jobrole      position   promotion_date
1   Robin   Sales           CEO 01/01/2012
1   Robin   Sales           CFO 20/01/2010
2   Jackman Sales - S1  EMP 01/04/2009
4   Sheldon Marketing   MGR 15/08/2012
4   Sheldon Marketing   SNRMGR  01/01/2011
4   Sheldon Marketing   MGR 01/01/2011
3   Arnold  Marketing   CEO 09/09/2009
5   Emmy    Marketing   SNRMGR  08/08/2008
6   Penny   Admin           SNRMGR  05/05/2012
6   Penny   Admin           MGR 09/09/2007
```

By ordering through the date these guys promoted, I need to capture the previous position held by the employee and adjacent to that current position. Is this possible ?

Below is what I required as Output

e_no e_name  e_job        prev_pos       curr_pos    promotion_date
    1   Robin   Sales       CFO         CEO          01/01/2012
    2   Jackman Sales - S1  Not Available   EMP          01/04/2009
    4   Sheldon Marketing   MGR         MGR          15/08/2012
    3   Arnold  Marketing   Not Available   CEO          09/09/2009
    5   Emmy    Marketing   Not Available   SNRMGR           08/08/2008
    6   Penny   Admin           MGR         SNRMGR           05/05/2012

Comment: What RDBMS?  SQL Server, MySQL, PGSQL?

Comment: I don't think your problem is well-defined, because an employee (Sheldon) can have two e_jobrole values at the same time. If Sheldon is promoted to VP and therefore another row is added (4,Sheldon,Marketing,VP, 06/01/2012), what will your desired output be? Sheldon in this case will not have just one previous job.

Comment: @Nav [This sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/6f555/30) might help who attempts to solve this. I didn't manage myself :/

Comment: Hi Steve, You are right so. Unfortunately, the data comes up with like that. But u can ignore that part , i will try to sort it out that part alone from end.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I seem to have been proven wrong just seconds after posting :P

I don't think you can do that in one query (except using a complicated stored procedure).

How about getting the data into an application (in Java, or whatever you would like) and then parse the data from the oldest data, and keeping track of the "previous position" of each employee. Then, whenever you get to one that you've already got a "previous position" for you can insert that into the table, and update the "previous position" (and if you haven't seen her before, set the "previous position" to null/"none"/""/etc).

Would that be useful, or would it have to be all done on the DB?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Basically I am trying to create report based on this data through SSRS. So I am intending to use DB alone to pull the required data.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. The combination of WHERE and HAVING may need some adjustment.

```
select 
  c.e_no, 
  c.e_name, 
  c.e_job, 
  p.position as prev_position, 
  c.position as curr_position, 
  c.promotion_date
from 
  emp c
inner join
  emp p
on 
  c.e_no=p.e_no
group by
  c.e_no, 
  c.e_name, 
  c.e_job, 
  p.position as prev_position, 
  c.position as curr_position, 
where 
  p.promotion_date < c.promotion_date
having 
  max(p.promotion_date),
  max(c.promotion_date)
```